# Flutter project displayed temp files also in left panel

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm opening my existing flutter project,In android studio left panel files it displays ._ temp files also for every files

Is there any solution for hiding that files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the pattern

```
._*
```

to ignored files and folders on **Settings -> Editor -> File types**

as below

[image: ignore files and folders]